# How to access database with username and password in Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm just a beginner with axios and javascript and would appreciate your help.

I have a database called `mydb` in MongoDb. To access this database, it is necessary to use the username `root` and password `example`.

Then I have a basic web app that allows registering new users in the database `mydb`. How can I update my `axios` script to access the database with the username `root` and password `example`.

This is my code:

```
const handleRegister = () => {
    if (username && password) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', username);
        formData.append('password', password);
        axios.post(config.api.url + '/auth/register', formData)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have a backend with `db.js` script:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dbURI = "mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/mydb?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass%20Community&ssl=false";

const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
};

// Connects the database to the server
mongoose.connect(dbURI, options).then(
    () => {
        console.log("Database connection established!");
    },
    err => {
        console.log("Error connecting Database instance due to: ", err);
    }
);
```

Comment: You should do that on your backend...

Comment: @FZs: Thanks, please see my update. This is what I have in the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (and you shouldn't) access your database from Javascript in a web browser (I'm assuming this as you're using axios).

You should create an API of some sort. That API should be the communication gateway between your JS and your database.

Comment: Thanks! Please see my update. Yes, I have a backend API. I can see "Database connection established!" message in logs. But still the web app that should register/add new users to `mydb` does not do so.

Comment: @Fluxy please show the actual code that is failing. How are you trying to register/add new users?

Comment: Sure, I see this error error message at the line `console.log(err)`: `Error: Network Error  at createError (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)`. I'm registering users through the simple form interface (web app).

Comment: I'm using `docker-compose` for my app and mongodb, if it's a relevant detail.

Comment: Also I see `xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:5000/auth/register net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. I think that it cannot find `localhost`

Comment: Which code is handling the requests at `/auth/register` ?